# Execution plan changes on same logic statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I get 2 different execution plans when I change the order in or condition?

First query runs immediately and the second works different and stack for couple of minutes.

I can't understand why.

**good execution plan**

```
    select findamittakul.recid,count(*) ct,max(c1.key5) key5 
    from 
    findamittakul join contact1 c1 on(tz=key1)  
                  join CONTACT2 c2 on(c1.accountno=c2.accountno )
    where
    c2.hp=findamittakul.hp
    and (c1.CREATEON =findamittakul.CREATEON or c1.CREATEON>findamittakul.createon )
    and c2.HAFKADABLOCK='' 
    and source=1 and c1.kupatype =3
    group by findamittakul.recid
```

**bad execution plan**

```
    select findamittakul.recid,count(*) ct,max(c1.key5) key5 
    from 
    findamittakul join contact1 c1 on(tz=key1)  
                  join CONTACT2 c2 on(c1.accountno=c2.accountno )
    where
    c2.hp=findamittakul.hp
    and (c1.CREATEON >findamittakul.CREATEON or c1.CREATEON=findamittakul.createon )
    --andc1.CREATEON >=findamittakul.CREATEON  --same plane
    and c2.HAFKADABLOCK ='' 
    and source=1 and c1.kupatype =3
    group by findamittakul.recid
```

Comment: Which database are you using, and what are the plans?

Comment: Hey Mark, It is Microsoft Sql, the first query uses some index on contact2 that is not used in the second plan, both queries are the same, the difference is in the order in or condition, marked by **

Comment: Does `"source='תקין'` really work? Those are unicode characters, so I would suspect not. Also, you shouldn't be using `ISNULL` in the `WHERE`; it ruins SARGability. Use *proper* `NULL` logic with `IS NULL`.

Comment: The order of the `OR` clauses is not semantically relevant, but the time at which the query was compiled is. If you change the text of either plan in a trivial manner (by adding a `-- comment` for example) I'd expect the recompiled plans to be the same. If so, the recourse is probably to make sure you have updated statistics.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, that is why I asked this question, I tried to compare in different servers, and to clear cash, I had the same results, the comment is the original query, I started to change from >= to = and then > and saw that it ran immediately and then changed the order to > and then = and had same problem

Comment: To share and compare the actual execution plans, you can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ .